# How to find by partial binary over BinData field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, nosql

I have a BinData field in my mongo and I need to make a find over it with partial information.

Let's say that the bindata that I have looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5480356518e91efd34e9b5f9"), "test" : BinData(0,"dGVzdA==") }
```

If I do this query I get the result:

```
> db.test.find({"test" : BinData(0,"dGVzdA==")})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5480356518e91efd34e9b5f9"), "test" : BinData(0,"dGVzdA==") }
```

However I would like to find it with only a part of the binary object.
Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What object are you storing as BinData ? If they are files, you could use GridFS and query on its metadata.

Comment: It's a byte[] and I want to query by it's content, not only the metadata

Comment: As of 2.6, MongoDB doesn't have operators to support searching part of a piece of BinData, unfortunately. I couldn't find a feature request for such a thing - if you like, you can make one in the [MongoDB JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER). As mnemosyn says, I think doing such a thing is more complicated than you might naively believe.

Comment: Thank you @wdberkeley . Yeah, I know is hard, that's why I asked :) Thanks for the info ;)

Comment: Well, there's a request for bitwise query operators (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3518) and support for `$bit` queries (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3281) with the following comment by a Pieter Willem Jordaan: 'This should also be applied to do queries over a section of binary data with an offset and length query'. However, the ticket is from June 2011...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"partial" is a vague term - if you're searching for a contiguous block of binary data (needle) at any point in the haystack, you're going to need a very different solution I think, maybe something based on a suffix tree / suffix array for binary data.

If you want to find binary data that *starts* with specific bytes, you might want to consider storing the data as hex or base64 encoded strings and use a rooted regex for index use. But that is fraught with its own perils (padding, endianness, etc.) and incredibly ugly...

Isn't there a way to store the binary data in a way that MongoDB understands it? That might be easier...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm looking for someway to make MongoDB to understand the binary so I can do searchs as you can do with texts for instance. Imagine that I have the "ab cd ef" bytes in a binary and I want to find those binaries which contain "cd" byte. I thought also of the posibility of representing it as hex but yeah, it's ugly and not too efficient in terms of space consumed.